# Cycles in mapping Domain models to DTOs

Tags: java, persistence, dto

can you tell me what is the best practice to mapping dto to domain and back for that object with has cycles? For example I have these 2 objects:
User object:

```
public class User {
   private int id;
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
   private List<Order> orders;
   // ... some other properties and getters and setters
}
```

and Order object:

```
public class Order {
   private int id;
   private User owner;
}
```

How should I mapping these domain models to DTOs? Here is example of my mapping function:

```
public UserDTO userToDto(User user) {
   UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();

   dto.setIs(user.getId());
   dto.setFirstname(user.getFirsname());
   dto.setLastname(user.getLastname());

   List<OrderDTO> ordersDto = new List<OrderDTO>();

   for (Order order : user.getOrders()) {
      OrderDTO orderDto = new OrderDTO();
      orderDto.setId(order.getId());
      orderDto.setUser(...) // what I should I set here?

      ordersDto.add(orderDto);
   }

   dto.setOrders(ordersDto);

   return dto;
}
```

I have problem with **orderDto.setUser(...)** function. Can you show my what is the best practice? When I start mapping properties of User step by step, I end with mapping Orders, which I actually mapping, and creates cycle. Thanks for answers.

Comment: I assume you will serialize these DTOs to JSON or XML. What will happen if they have cycles? What do you deduce?

Comment: I did not create service yet. I just impement task to my school project, and I thinking about implementation. When I start implement User properties into userToDto function, one of these properties is List of Orders, so next I started mapping Order's properties where is User again and so on ... it cycle. And my question is how to avoid this and what is the best practice. I hope is that explaining more clearer.

Comment: @davidxxx I can't use you code, because OrderDTO has reference to UserDTO  not User. I need map properties from User to UserDTO properties.

Comment: I'm trying to make you think here. The DTO should not be designed based on what the entities are. It should be designed based on what you want the client to receive. What will happen if they have cycles? What do you conclude?

Comment: @JBNizet so if I start mapping User to UserDTO it will be infinity process right? I never before implement these, so maybe my idea is wrong, can you give me example what should I do? My task from school is not well defined. I know only that I should map entities to dtos. So I tried it mapped it 1:1.

Comment: @JBNizet UserDTO on client should contains User properties + Orders of that User in List. But everyone order has informations about User, and in these informations are also list of Orders. So when I append that list to User, it cycly. I'm sorry I don't know ho to better explain it. Do you know what I mean ?

Comment: Yes. So, you're telling me that those cycles will make the code turn into an infinite recursive loop, right? Do you consider an infinite loop to be a best practice? What do you conclude about cycles? Does the client, asking about a user and his/her orders, need to have the user inside the order? What do you conclude? Again, I'm not asking you to describe your problem. I'm asking you to find out the answer by yourself by answering my questions.

Comment: @JBNizet yes client require user and orders but only in one nested level, more levels are unnecessary

Comment: Then why would you add more levels, especially if they cause an infinite loop?

Comment: @JBNizet because I didn't know if it is good practice. So in nested levels should I keep it as null?

Comment: You shouldn't even have a user field in OrderDTO, since you don't want a user there.

Comment: How to do that? Should I create another DTO without that property?

Comment: Well, just remove the field from the OrderDTO. If another use case needs an order DTO with a user, then use two different DTOs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I assume you need the relation on the client side, too. Otherwise you wouldn't have a problem with the cycle anyways.
Further I assume you have both a UserDTO and OrderDTO, where the OrderDTO has UserDTO as member (and UserDTO a list of OrderDTOs).

Imho you simply have to set

```
orderDTO.setUser(dto); // where dto is the UserDTO created initially.
```

Now you get a cycle, which you need to handle when sending the DTO to the client (e.g. using Rest). On the JPA side you likely have something like @OneToOne (in Order) and @OneToMany (in User) annotations.

I'd recommend jackson for JSON processing. If you do so you can use

```
// in UserDTO
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Orders> orders;

// in OrdersDTO
@JsonBackReference
private UserDTO owner;
```

I hope this helps!